# Asymptotic analysis of a program

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science, complexity-theory

Can you give the asymptotic analysis of this

```
i = 1;
k = 1;

while(k<n){
    k = k+ i;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

I have tried analysing but I was stuck at the inner loop

Comment: Of good first step would be to figure out the sequence of values taken by variable `k`.

Comment: Its actually the first sum of positive number of i, but am concerned about BIG O of it

Comment: @MusaIbrahim If you can find the sequence of values taken by `k`, then it is easy to find how many such values are required until `k>=n`. This will be the number of iterations your loop will make, and will give you the time complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let  be the number of the iteration, then the values of  and  evolve as follows:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1+1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1+1+2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1+1+2+3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1+1+2+3+4 | 5 |

So we see that  is 1 + ∑<sub><sub>=1</sub></sub>

This sum is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), and so:

= 1 + (+1)/2

And if we fix  to the total number of iterations, then:

1 + (-1)/2 <  ≤ 1 + (+1)/2.

So  is O(²), and thus  is O(√).

The number of iterations  is a measure of the complexity, so it is O(√).